# Load a child component on click of parent component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a button component that loads comments. The comments are a separate component.

How can on click of the button can I load a child component? Is it a simple case of using v-if on the child component? Or is there a more efficient way?

e.g.

```
<template>
    <div class="comment-btn" @click="toggleActive">
         <img src="/img/comment-btn.svg">
    </div>

    <comments v-if="active"></comments>
</template>
```

EDIT:

I've been reading about mount, would that be better?

Comment: I think `v-if` is fine in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`v-if` and `v-show` are both perfectly acceptable options. The questions you'll need to ask yourself, however, are "do I need the child component to do anything on being toggled?" and "do I need any data in the child component to be persisted?". Based on your exact program needs, you'll want to choose accordingly.

Here is a general description of the solutions you'll need based on your answers:
1) If you don't need anything to happen on toggling but you need data persisted, use `v-show`.
2) If you don't need anything to happen on toggling and you want data to be cleared out, use `v-if`.
3) If you need something to happen on toggling and you want data persisted, use `v-if` and the `mounted` lifecycle hook for triggering the event, and `$emit` any data to your parent component so it can be restored later. Alternatively, use `v-show` and a `watch` a particular `props` value.
4) If you need something to happen on toggling and don't need your data persisted, then just use `v-if` and the `mounted` lifecycle hook for triggering the event.